# Redirect all request to a subfolder, with exceptions

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I am having the following problem with Apache 2.2:

I need to redirect all `/` requests to `/new/` (an existing folder), except when the URI is `/old/`, a virtual folder which contains the `/` directory itself. For example:

`/` directory:

```
<new>
a.php
```

Thus when I request for `/a.php`, it redirects to `/new/a.php`, but if I request for `/old/a.php`, it returns the `/a.php` file.

So far, I got this, which does redirect `/a.php` to `/new/a.php`, but always fail for the `/old/a.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^old/(.*) /$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) new/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Any ideas what I got wrong?

I must point out that I do not have access to httpd.conf, just to folders, so I must use the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} old/?(.*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,QSA]

# redirect requests from / to /new/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ new/ [L,R=302,QSA]

# redirect requests from /..... to /new/.....
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !old/?  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !new/?
RewriteRule ^(.*) new/$1 [L,R=302,QSA]
```

Unfortunately, this is not the best solution, since requests to `/a.php` will return the `/a.php`, instead of `/new/a.php`, but requests to `/b.php` will redirect to `/new/b.php` and requests to `/old/a.php` will return `/a.php`

Answer (score 0):

use a RewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^old/
RewriteRule ^(.*) new/$1 [L,R=302]    
RewriteRule ^old/(.*) /$1 [L]
```

Comment: Even when using this, I am redirected to `/new/old/`, which does not change the behavior from what I had.